# Find an SO(3) matrix which satisfies some linear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, rotations

I have the following optimization problem:

$\displaystyle \min_R \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^T R Y_i)^2$

where $R \in \text{SO}(3)$, i.e. is a 3x3 rotation matrix, and $X_i,Y_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

If $n \le 6$, and I allow $R$ to be any 3x3 matrix, then I can compute a basis for $R$ from the null space of:

$\displaystyle A = \left[ \text{vec}(Y_1X_1^T), ..,\text{vec}(Y_nX_n^T)\right]$

so an equivalent problem is to find an $R \in \text{SO}(3)$ which is either in or closest to the null space of $A$. It seems that this might be a generalization of the orthogonal Procrustes problem.

Do any linear or eigen-decomposition-based solutions exist? If not, what methods have been used to efficiently solve this type of problem?

Comment: You are trying to minimize a quadratic in $R_{ij}$ subject to several $\sum R_{ij}R_{ik}=\delta_{jk}$.  Will Lagrange multipliers work?

Comment: Not sure. The constraints are quadratic, so I'll still have a non-linear problem to solve. It will have no constraints, but equally I could do an optimization on the SO(3) manifold using Lie algebra, also avoiding the constraints. Both are iterative approaches. Not sure which is better, though the latter would be seeking a minimum, the former a stationary point (stability issues?). Hoping for something closed-form still.